# How to add React-bootstrap Modal when webpage open for every time

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to add React-bootstrap Modal when website open for the every time, model should always pop up in center with the details and with option of close  the model.

I tried this approach but it fails:

```
 const Modals = (props) => {

  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => setModalShow(false);

  return (
    <div>

     <Modal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={handleClose}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Public Notice
    </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <p>
                Dear Friends and Mandir Devotees.
            </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>

   </div>
  );
};

export default Modals;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Modals.js**

```
const Modals = (props) => {

  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => setModalShow(false);

  return (
    <div>

     <Modal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={handleClose}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Public Notice
    </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <p>
                Dear Friends and Mandir Devotees.
            </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>

   </div>
  );
};

export default Modals;
```

Use **Modals.js** in your **App.js**

```
render(){
  <Modals />
}
```

Comment: setShow is not defined  const handleClose = () => setShow(setModalShow);

Comment: I have updated the code. @PURU, Let me know if you get any other error.

Comment: Thanks @Sarthak Aggarwal as i am new in reactjs why did you write show (show={modalShow}) what if i write only {modalShow} and can you tell me why <Modal.Header closeButton> is not working

Comment: @PURU, `show={modalShow}`, in layman terms says that `show` property of Modal is connected with `modalShow` state property of our component. So, if `modalShow` is false, it means `show={false}` and vice-versa. Updated my code for `closeButton`. Check if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Sarthak Aggarwa it means show is just a property

Comment: @PURU Basically, `Modal` provided by bootstrap is also a component, so you are passing props to it.